# Get Asterisk HangupCauseCode using linphone?

Tags: android, asterisk, linphone, linphone-sdk

I am working with linphone call feature using Asterisk server. I have set call limit to one(1) in asterisk server for every sip users. So it will permit only 1 outgoing call and 1 incoming call at a time. Now I want to know if other user calls to user which is already busy with other call then how can I realize that, the end user is busy? Is there any way to get that using linphone lib? Or is there any way to get Asterisk **HangupCauseCode** using linphonelib?

I have checked with `LinphoneCall.getReason()` while **CallEnd** state but it returns **null**.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your dialplan and save somewhere DIALSTATUS variable after dial attempt.

Comment: Thanks for reply. can you guide me with example?

Comment: Are you kidding? This example on start of every asterisk book.